# How to detect ear piece (speaker) availability on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I want to detect specially on iPad's if there is ear piece available or not.

For example - I can detect if the iOS device hasTourch or not using AVFoundation so is there any way to detect ear piece availability.

Answer (score 3):

**1) If you want to check if Ear piece (Receiver speaker) is available on device**

You can identify this by simply identifying if Device is iPhone.

UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone

in iOS prottype `AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver` is there  for builtInreceriver speaker. 
and according to [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosessionportbuiltinreceiver), This is available only on iPhone device. So there is no need to check for anything else, If its iPhone, You have Ear piece  and if its not iPhone (on ipad) it don't have ear piece.

**2)  If you want to check if head phone is connected or not:**

You can use currentroute of share audio session to check if headset is connected or not:
here is sample function in **swift 3.0**

```
   func IsHeadSetConnected() -> Bool{
        let route  = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute;
        for desc   in route.outputs
        {
            let portType = desc.portType;
            if (portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
```

You should also monitor its status by listening for route change:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleRouteChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionRouteChange, object: nil)
```

here is sample code for handler of notification setup above:

```
func handleRouteChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
    let reasonRaw = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? NSNumber,
    let reason = AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason(rawValue: reasonRaw.uintValue)
    else { fatalError("Strange... could not get routeChange") }
    switch reason {
    case .oldDeviceUnavailable:
        print("oldDeviceUnavailable")
    case .newDeviceAvailable:
        print("headset/line plugged in")
    case .routeConfigurationChange:
        print("headset pulled out")
    case .categoryChange:
        print("Just category change")
    default:
        print("not handling reason")
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your question after noticing your comment on other answer. so updated my answer accordingly. Hope that will help!

Comment: I’m now facing a another problem, maybe you would have any idea to fix it :
**1 -** I plug a headphone -> my audio route change callback is called.
**2 -** then I switch sound to speakers (without unplugging my headphone) -> audio route change callback is called.
**3 -** then I unplug my headphone (when sound is still outputting to speakers) -> audio route change callback is NOT called, which seems logical.

But here is my problem ! So my question is : Do you see a way to detect that headphone was unplugged for this last case ?

Comment: @Nilesh did u figure out the solution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:

```
    import AVFoundation    

    let currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute

    for description in currentRoute.outputs {
        if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortLineOut {

        }else if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones {

        }else if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP{

        }else if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver{

        }else if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker{

        }else if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHDMI{

        }else if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay{

        }else if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothLE{

        }
    }
```

Reference:

Apple document: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosessionportdescription/1669281-output_port_types

Comment: I would suggest using `switch` instead of `if/else if/.../else if`

Comment: @Pang Ho Ming is there any way to record the sound from ear piece ?

Answer (score 1):

One liner **Swift 4+** solution to:

Detect if built-in-mic is available

```
let isMicAvailable: Bool = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs?.first(where: { $0.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic }) != nil
```

Detect if the Ear piece (Receiver speaker) is available

```
let isEarPieceAvailable: Bool = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.outputs.first(where: { $0.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver }) != nil
```

Answer (score 0):

The short and simplest way is to check via `contains`.

```
func isHeadphonesConnected() -> Bool{
    let routes = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    return routes.outputs.contains(where: { (port) -> Bool in
        port.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones
    })
}
```

Comment: Actually like iPhone we can switch between speaker and ear piece but in iPad we do have speaker only, I am concerned if some models do have earpiece speaker like phones, so I want to detect if a device has earpiece or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check for

```
if let availableInputs = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs {
        for route in availableInputs {
            if ( route.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic ) {
                //built-in-mic available
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if built-in-mic is available.

```
var isMicAvailable = false
if let availableInputs = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs {
    for route in availableInputs {
        if ( route.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic ) {
            //built-in-mic available
            isMicAvailable = true
            break;
        }
    }
}
print("current device has mic - \(isMicAvailable)")
```

Another way to to check if current device is iPhone.

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]) {
    //current device is iPhone.
}
```