# iOS: how to check if the speaker is on

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

I used `AVAudioSession`'s `overrideOutputAudioPort`method to play sound in the speaker in iOS. [overrideOutputAudioPort](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616443-overrideoutputaudioport?language=objc)

How can we check if the output audio is overrided as speaker, in a word if the sound is played by the speaker ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check it by using `currentRoute` Consider below code for that:

```
let currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute

    for output in currentRoute.outputs {

        switch output.portType {

        case AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker:
            print("Speaker is on.")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

You can refer [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessionport?language=objc) for more info.

And original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374565/how-to-detect-ear-piece-speaker-availability-on-ios-devices). but its with `if` checks but `switch` is better to use according to me.

And you can detect other outputs as mentioned in apple doc.

Comment: Is `AVAudioSessionPortLineOut ` for the speaker?

Comment: I think it is if it's connected with doc but anyway you can check other options from doc if that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: I wonder if currentRoute.outputs contains only the used ports.

Comment: Dharmesh I have to use `AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker` to check if the speaker is open.

Comment: `AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker` is renamed to `AVAudioSession.Port.builtInSpeaker` (from XCode IDE popup)